# Fidler not capturing my computer web requests

Tags: proxy, telerik, fiddler, proxy-server

I recently configured an azure virtual machine so i can access it via remote desktop
then i install Fidler application on it so i can set it up as a proxy server

after that i went back to my local computer that have an internet connection and i set up my proxy settings as follow

[image]
**strong text**
Though the proxy server is not capturing any request coming from my local pc
is there anything that i have missed? below is the server

[image]

Comment: Make sure in the advanced dialog the option "use proxy for all protocols) is enabled. What client program have you used on your computer? Some programs ignore proxy settings. Why not simply run Fiddler on your local computer? Less pain and no insecure network connection (open port of Fiddler on the Azure VM).

Comment: i am using IE ( internet explorer)

Comment: Please don't use IE...